# Constructing a differential equation involving local isometries

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I bet there must be some research about this topic I'm not able to find.
Suppose I have a smooth surface patch $\sigma_0$ I want to construct a local isometry $\sigma_{\infty}$ with some specific property, for example the curvature of $\sigma_\infty$ must be $0$ ideally (or in practice as low as possible).

Formally speaking I'm looking for a representation of a local isometry that *flats*. The first problem I struggle with is what class of surfaces $\sigma_0$ have the property that can be flattened. Assuming the input can be transformed into a flat one the only way I thought of constructing such transformation would be by means of a differential equation

$$
\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t} = f(D\sigma)
$$

($D$ is a differential operator) or maybe using a second order differential equation. I have the feeling a problem like this in these terms has been already tackled ad I'd like to see some papers, but I really struggle to find anything.

Can anyone suggest some readings maybe?

I believe it can be modelled as

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( J_{\sigma_t}^T J_{\sigma_t}^T \right) = 0 \\
\sigma_0 = \text{given} \\
\mathcal{W}_{\sigma_{\infty}} = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Where $\mathcal{W}$ is the shape operator (2 x 2 matrix describing the curvature).

Thank you